# Error in R.java when creating a spinner with url's

Tags: android, url

I want to use a spinner to set a variable to an url. Every thing went well, till the R.java was build. I got 2 error:

> duplicate R.string.http_

and

> Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration

So now my question is how to fix this error, while I can't change the R.java file?
Here's my code.
The R.java file:

```
    public static final class string {
    public static final int Mijngroep=0x7f050001;
    public static final int app_name=0x7f050000;
    public static final int http_//www_admiraalkruys_nl/nieuws_htm=0x7f050002;
    public static final int http_//www_alexandergroep_nl/=0x7f050004;
    public static final int http_//www_anthonievandiemenstam_nl/=0x7f050005;
    public static final int http_//www_scoutingbeverwijk_nl/=0x7f050003;
```

And the strings.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Groep kiezer</string>
<string name="Mijngroep">Selecteer jouw groep</string>  
<string name="http://www.admiraalkruys.nl/nieuws.htm">Admiraal kruysgroep</string>  
<string name="http://www.scoutingbeverwijk.nl/">Admiraal van Kinsbergen</string>  
<string name="http://www.alexandergroep.nl/">Alexandergroep</string>  
<string name="http://www.anthonievandiemenstam.nl/">Anthonie van diemenstam</string>  
</resources>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your string names, if you use two successive slashes it will be interpreted as a java comment (`//`) in the R.java file.

EDIT :

In fact you should remove every special character because they are invalid characters in java for a variable name. For example you can remove the `http://` part, and replace the special chars with underscores :

```
<string name="www_admiraalkruys_nl_nieuws_htm">Admiraal kruysgroep</string>  
....
```

Comment: No, it's not possible to use an url as a name. But you can reverse the name and value : `<string name="Admiraal_kruysgroep">http://www.admiraalkruys.nl/nieuws.htm</string>`

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of the resources and clean and build your project in order to clean and rebuild your R generated file.

Hope this helps!